# JQuery / Ajax isset (MyFunction) always returns false

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've written a php function to generate a random math question for anti-spam purposes. It sets a question and the answer to two session variables.

In the HTML file I call the function in the document ready event and send the results to the div for the question, this works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({

        url: "sec.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"GetQA":""},
        success: function(data) {   
            $("#no_spam_Q").replaceWith(data);
        }
    });

});
```

What I'm having trouble with is refreshing the text of the question after the user clicks a submit button.

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit", function () {

    var comment = document.getElementById('comment').value
    var no_spam = document.getElementById('no_spam').value

    $.ajax({ 

        type:"POST", 
        url: "comments-set.php", 
        dataType: "html",
        data:{no_spam, comment:comment}, 
        success: function(data){ 

            $("#display").html(data); 

            $.ajax({

                url: "sec.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {"GetQA":""},
                success: function(data) {   
                    $("#no_spam_Q").replaceWith(data);
                }
            });

        }
    }); 

});
```

Here the nested ajax call is supposed to refresh the question & answer but it always *appears* to fail.

PHP:

```
session_start();

Function GetQA($str){

    // some code to generate the question & answer

    return $secFinal;

}

if (isset($_POST['GetQA'])) {
    echo GetQA($_POST['GetQA']);
}else{
    echo "not set";
}
```

The php always returns "not set" and so the anti-spam question text doesn't change. In another PHP file that checks the answer I echo the right answer if a wrong answer is given (just for debugging). The confusing thing is even though "not set" is being returned a new answer is generated, because entering the same answer twice fails my check and the echo message about the correct answer is shown.

I'm guessing this has something to do with the query being async but despite reading the API and other SO questions for many hours I'm none the wiser on how to solve it.

Here's what I've tried:

- [deferred.done()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)
- Moving the nested call to GetQA from the success function to a 
  [.mouseup()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseup/) event for the submit button
- Moving the function from success and running it after the call to comment-set.php

On another note I'm passing an empty string to GetQA because the the compiler complains if i just use `data: {"GetQA"}` - how can I call a function without paramenters?

Comment: You must have to pass `GetQA` parameter in side `data:{no_spam, comment:comment}`. It will always return false because you never set it in the second call

Comment: Thanks, but I'm new to JS and don't get what you mean - can expand on your comment a little more please, or perhaps post an answer?

Comment: php isset function check for if key / variable is set or not.  Here in second ajax call you are not passing the `GetQA` parameters ( `data:{no_spam, comment:comment}` ). So on server inside `$_POST` it will never find the `GetQA` key inside the variable. That's why it is falling in else part of the condition. You can avoid the problem by passing `GetQA` just having blank string. like this `data:{no_spam, comment:comment, GetQA : ''}`

Comment: No that doesn't work at all, it generates a new answer before returning from comment-set.php so the answer is always wrong